# Duality of plurisubharmonic functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, duality

Let $F$ be a cone of upper bounded upper semicontinuous functions on a compact set set $X$ containing all the constants.    Let $z\in X $ and define a class of positive measure by $$M_z^F=\{ \mu : u(z)\leq \int_X u  d\mu \mbox{ for all } u\in F\} $$

Let $g: X\rightarrow R$ and set  $$Sg(z)=\sup\{u\in F, u\leq g\}$$ $$ Ig(z)=\inf\{ \int_X g  d\mu , \mu\in M^F_z\}   \}$$

The following statement correspond to Edwards theorem  : With $F$  as above , and if $g $ is a bounded Borel function on $X$, then $Sg(z)\leq Ig(z)$. If $g$ is lower semicontinuous , then $Sg=Ig$.

One can find an example in Frank Wikstrom  Paper (Jensen measure and boundary value of plurisubharmonic functions)  and  also  in Ransford paper showing that if $g$ is upper semi-continuous then $Sg\not= Ig$.  \

Can any body tell me whether the upper semi-continuous regularizations coincide in general case? i.e  $(Sg)^*(z)=(Ig)^*(z)$  (or when g is upper semi-continuous).